# Function inserting json array elements into a table

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

How to write a Postgres function that receives a JSONB array value and iterates over it to insert the elements in a relational table?

**JSON**

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "John"},{"id": 2, "name": "Mary"}]
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Names (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(50)
)
```

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION
  Insert_Names(IN data JSONB)
$$
  FOR ...
     INSERT INTO Names VALUES (...)
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to unpack the table and the operator `->>` to get text values of the elements. Cast the values to appropriate types if necessary.

```
insert into names
select (elem->>'id')::int, elem->>'name'
from jsonb_array_elements('[{"id": 1, "name": "John"},{"id": 2, "name": "Mary"}]') as arr(elem)
returning *

 id | name 
----+------
  1 | John
  2 | Mary
(2 rows)
```

The function may look like this:

```
create or replace function insert_names(jsonb)
returns void language sql as $$
    insert into names
    select (elem->>'id')::int, elem->>'name'
    from jsonb_array_elements($1) as arr(elem)
$$;

select insert_names('[{"id": 1, "name": "John"},{"id": 2, "name": "Mary"}]');
```

Alternatively, you can use the function `jsonb_populate_recordset()` which allows even simpler syntax:

```
create or replace function insert_names(jsonb)
returns void language sql as $$
    insert into names
    select *
    from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::names, $1)
$$;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.